# Add column in dict with partial key in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Setting up dict:

```
rr = range(1,11)
ft =[('sd:jan:'+ str(x), 'News') for x in rr]    
fd = dict(ft)

 fd
    {'sd:jan:1': 'News',
     'sd:jan:10': 'News',
     'sd:jan:2': 'News',
     'sd:jan:3': 'News',
     'sd:jan:4': 'News',
     'sd:jan:5': 'News',
     'sd:jan:6': 'News',
     'sd:jan:7': 'News',
     'sd:jan:8': 'News',
     'sd:jan:9': 'News'}

fd.keys()

['sd:jan:10',
 'sd:jan:2',
 'sd:jan:3',
 'sd:jan:1',
 'sd:jan:6',
 'sd:jan:7',
 'sd:jan:4',
 'sd:jan:5',
 'sd:jan:8',
 'sd:jan:9']
```

How would add all values of 'jan' in the key?

EDIT: where I am adding the values (1+2+3+4+5+6+...+10) for the partial key of "jan."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
sum(int(i.split(':')[-1]) for i in fd.keys())
```

gives:

```
55
```

Splits each entry by `:`, grabs the last field, converts to int and sums them up.

In case you'd needed to examine the numbers, or wanted them for some reason later you could easily collect them in a list using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[int(i.split(':')[-1]) for i in fd.keys()]
```

Comment: @Merlin changed to generator expression :-) .. less memory hungry. Love the compact Python syntax

Comment: I can use %time in ipython to test time @ r of 300,000. Is there a way to check memory???

Comment: @Merlin are you asking if there's a way to know memory consumption? I don't know, but I'd love to know how to find out, it would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid it, you shouldn't convert the numbers to strings to start with if you want to do something with them later as numbers.  How about this:

```
rr = range(1,11)
ft =[(('sd','jan',x), 'News') for x in rr]    
fd = dict(ft)

tot = sum(val
   for (key, subkey, val) in fd
   if subkey == 'jan')

>>>tot
55
```

Comment: I dont have control over creation of "fd"

Comment: Well, then the `if you can avoid it` is relevant. ;)  In your case, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
len([i for i in fd if i[3:6] == 'jan'])
```

Create list comprehension, filter it by the 'jan' substring (`[3:6]`). Count the resulting list using `len`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in fd:
if 'jan' in key:
    total=total+int(key.split(':')[-1])
```